# Is it possible to run angular js app directly on mobile

Tags: angularjs

i just want to know that is it possible to run angularjs app on mobile directly means without using web browser??
I search google and it seems i can't but my client want to do that.

Comment: You should google native mobile applications with angularjs, first record that I found: https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-is-how-you-build-native-mobile-apps-with-angular

Comment: Yes/No answer type questions are *rarely* useful for this site.

Comment: but it become web app not mobile app with native frame work.I want a mobile app.

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for improve your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also use Ionic Framework (ionicframework.com) for this as it is heavily using Angular and encapsulating everything in real mobile apps that are capable of being deployed via App Stores (Play Store, iTunes, ...).

Best regards,
Steviee

Comment: but sir i think its make a web app but i want a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cordova Framework Which generates mobile application in android and ios also for that you can refer -https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/
Follow this documentation step and you get all files with proper structure in that you can write your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Try angular bundler for cordova.

abc framework - https://github.com/thruthesky/abcframework which gives you a great convenient building mobile apps using Angular.

abc is Angular Bundler for Cordova which helps you building mobile apps with Angular.